# Converting an Object (var) that contains a DataSet to an actual DataSet

Tags: c#, xml

I'm storing a DataSet in Session, and it's currently stored as an object. I've strained my poor brain googling and trying various methods.

Need help on how to do it.

Full code pasted:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents["StatusInformation"] == null)
        {
            DataSet ATServerURLList = new DataSet("ATServerURLList");
            ATServerURLList.Tables.Add(Populate.ReturnURLList());
            Session["StatusInformation"] = new DataSet();
            Session["StatusInformation"] = XMLManager.RetrieveXML(ATServerURLList);
            Session["TimeXMLRetrieved"] = new DateTime();
            Session["TimeXMLRetrieved"] = DateTime.Now;
        }
        DateTime DateTimeNowForComparison = DateTime.Now; //Gets TimeNow for Comparison
        var TimeXMLRetrievedVar = Session["TimeXMLRetrieved"]; //Pulls the time the last XML was retrieved and stores it in a variable
        DateTime TimeXMLRetrievedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(TimeXMLRetrievedVar); //Takes the Time XML was retrieved and stores it in a DateTime
        TimeSpan ComparisonResult = DateTimeNowForComparison.Subtract(TimeXMLRetrievedDateTime); //Subtracts the time the XML was retrived from the TimeNow
        if (ComparisonResult.TotalHours > 12)
        {
            DataSet ATServerURLList = new DataSet("ATServerURLList");
            ATServerURLList.Tables.Add(Populate.ReturnURLList());
            Session["StatusInformation"] = new DataSet();
            Session["StatusInformation"] = XMLManager.RetrieveXML(ATServerURLList);
            Session["TimeXMLRetrieved"] = new DateTime();
            Session["TimeXMLRetrieved"] = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

//Everything is fine up to here, don't need help with the above part. Just need to convert var dsServersVar from the DataSet stored in Session to an actual DataSet.

```
        var dsServersVar = Session["StatusInformation"];
            //gridStatusCustomersOverviewNotPaid.DataSource = dsServers.Tables["StatusCustomersOverviewNotPaid"];
            //gridStatusCustomersOverviewNotPaid.DataBind();
    }
```

I've currently tried Converter, Convert, and Convert.ChangeType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need is a cast:

```
DataSet dsServersVar = (DataSet)Session["StatusInformation"];
```

I usually fix this by introducing a class that holds the session variables and makes them accessible in an easy way.

Something like:

```
public static class SessionVariables
{
    public static DataSet StatusInformation
    {
        get
        {
            return (DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Session["StatusInformation"];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["StatusInformation"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help regardless.

Comment: @ChristopherHanka https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Comment: Dude these are so useful! I've done these 3-way operations before where I change from some type to another using Convert.Whatever and then convert again before I can actually use it.